# JPQL Select range start index with entity id

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jpql

I would like to use pagination in a restful web service. I found a lot of code how to get results of a table between two hard coded values (like between 10-20) but i need to set the start index a little bit different. I want to select from a table the 20 rows after a certain id.
Example:

```
rowNo     id
  1       22
  2       56
  3       98
  4       24
  5       75
  6       27
  7       59
  8       45
  9       32
  10      85
```

now i want to select 5 items after the id 24. So the result table should look like this:

```
rowNo     id
  1       75
  2       27
  3       59
  4       45
  5       32
```

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

try to use that constraction:

```
public List(int first, int pageSize) {
 CriteriaBuilder...
 CriteriaQuery....
 Predicates.....

  TypedQuery<T> typedQuery = entitymanager.createQuery(CriteriaQuery);
   if (pageSize >= 0){
        typedQuery.setMaxResults(pageSize);
    }
    if (first >= 0){
        typedQuery.setFirstResult(first);
    }
    return typedQuery.getResultList();
}
```